# Payment address of other country in google play console

Tags: google-play-console, google-pay

I moved to another country and my personal payment address is no longer valid. Google's recommendation is to create another payment account with the actual address. But it makes me wonder:

1. Taxes of which country is going to be applied to my payments?
2. Do I need to verify my address the same way as in AdMob? Via verification PIN. And if yes, then what address they will send it to?
3. How do I withdraw the money I will earn? Is it through the AdSense system or somehow different?

Why do I wonder, you may ask? That's because I was forced to create totally new AdMob account when I moved to another country, but here Google says that it's enough to have just an additional payment address. Am I good?

Answer (score 1):

On your original AdMob Account Add new payment method (new bank account from your new country) then cancel the first payment method (your old bank account)

Call AdMob Support and verify your new address, they will ask for a bill with your name or Bank statement from your new address (make sure your name in statement is identical to your passport and the new address is written in English)

Also they will ask you to fill W-8 form to identify if you working for USA or not.

Remember to close the new AdMob account if this worked properly.

The tax will apply to the country of the bank account which received the payment.